# Using Babel Compiler?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

JS 6 will be slowly rolling out as the main browsers choose to implement its features.  Babel 5 was created to compile a JS 5 version to shortcut the process.

Is Babel 5 a good option or might it create more problems than it is worth?  Is it better to follow the long, slow path to ES 6 implementation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll still need to support browsers that don't have ES6 support yet. It may likely be several years before all browsers support ES6 natively.

Babel is a good option if you want to skip the wait while still having all the perks of ES6.

Comment: Thanks.  Are there any advantages to not using Babel, and waiting for the native support of the browsers?

Comment: The resulting code may not be the most straightforward, and it introduces another step into your build process. I think that these are relatively trivial. Another thing to consider is that you'll need to maintain and debug any issues that arise via the transpilation process, if they're unique to that code base.